# How can I write a voice command in Dragon NaturallySpeaking that holds a key down for X seconds?

Tags: keyboard, naturallyspeaking

How can I write a voice command in Dragon NaturallySpeaking that holds a key down for X seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following voice command will hold the key <kbd>CTRL</kbd> for three seconds. You can change the key as well as how long the key is being hold down.

```
' Tested with Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate
' From http://nuance-community.custhelp.com/posts/2cd74d2484
' Lindsay Adam
' www.pcbyvoice.com

Declare Function keybd_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As _
Long, bScan As Long, ByVal Flag As Long, ByVal exInfo As Long) As Long

' You can find all the virtual key codes in the following link:
' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx
Const VK_CTRL = 17

Sub Main
    keybd_event(VK_CTRL,0,0,0)
    Wait(3)
    keybd_event(VK_CTRL,0,2,0)
End Sub
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx (their robots.txt doesn't allow me to mirror their website with https://web.archive.org):

[image]